# Is it possible to setup development mode environment on running Ubuntu machine (Server) for vuejs project

Tags: node.js, apache, vue.js, web-development-server

I have a vuejs project in my local machine (With development mode) as on local machine I can run vue project in development mode and I have the full feature of the instant update (Like Hot reloading).
Now I want to set up this exact environment on a live machine (ubuntu) where I can use the feature like hot reloading on the Live machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue your devlopements on this live machine you will not want to build it each time you modify something so just run your usual script  (npm run serve / yarn serve). This script use development as default environment variable (see https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html).

If you still want to build it, I think you will must build it each time you modify something no matter the environment variable due to the generation of new files.

Hope this help you.